# Using Liquid Markup without a server

Tags: html, liquid

I need to create an html page that works with Liquid Markup. To do that I am trying to get the standalone template. But when I try to get the template, I see talks of Ruby on Rails, etc. I have never used Ruby on Rails and I would rather not start right now. I am pure html, css, javascript developer. Is there a simple way to get the standalone Liquid Markup with my current background? Also I have used jinja2 for a python client. If I code the html page to jinja2, will it work with Liquid Markup?

Comment: Are there liquid markup viewers? or Editors or Engines? I don't know what to call it. It would be nice to have such a thing without having to open a shopify account. I think that is the gist of this question. So I wonder if someone would not mind sharing a short list. Just a viewer or IDE that does not require much more.

Comment: Hi @BrendonMuir could you please help with this question?